# Стиль текста при вводе в textarea

Tags: html, css, textarea, кроссбраузерность

Доброго времени суток! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как изменить стиль **текста при вводе в поле** `textarea`? Кроссбраузерно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Берёте и прописываете ему стили, в чём проблема-то?
Например,

```css
#editor {
  color: red;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 20;
}
```

```html
<textarea id='editor'>Я красный текст размера 20 начертанием Verdana</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если ваша задача изменить цвет куска текста, то на это textarea не способен (тут поищите в инете, как сделать), если всего текста, то просто используйте css, не знаете, как работать в css, тогда изучайте!